# drools 5.0.1 vs 6.0.1 API changes?

Tags: drools

We are upgrading our application from drools 5.0.1 to drools 6.0.1 Final. I noticed there are some API changes. Many classes that used to be in org.drools appear to be now in org.drools.core. Also, the class DebugRuleFlowEventListener appears to no longer exist.

My question is: is there a documentation somewhere explaining the API differences between the two versions? Unless I'm missing something, it seems like they are significant and should be documented. Also, thought I was tasked with the upgrade I wasn't the one who developed so I'm far from being an expert on drools.

If there is no such documentation - can anyone advise what to do about DebugRuleflowEventListener?
Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 3):

A big focus for 6.0 was streamlining the build, deploy and loading(utilization) aspects of the system. Building and deploying now align with Maven and the utilization is now convention and configuration oriented, instead of programmatic, with sane default to minimise the configuration.

Two primary distributions consist of:

**KIE Drools Workbench**

- Drools Editors, for rules and supporting assets.
- jBPM Designer, for Rule Flow and supporting assets.

**KIE Workbench**

- Drools Editors, for rules and supporting assets.
- jBPM Designer, for BPMN2 and supporting assets.
- jBPM Console, runtime and Human Task support.
- jBPM Form Builder.
- BAM.

Regarding API would suggest looking at [OFFICIAL DOCS](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/kie-api-javadoc/)

There are three debug classes:

- DebugAgendaEventListener
- DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener
- DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener

Some of the methods `afterRuleFlowGroupActivated(RuleFlowGroupActivatedEvent event)` and `afterRuleFlowGroupDeactivated(RuleFlowGroupDeactivatedEvent event)` which existed in `DebugRuleFlowEventListener` are moved to `DebugAgendaEventListener`

Hoping was able to help to some extent.

Cheers !!